# WSO2 ESB + Apache httpd

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I have apache httpd server which I would like to configure to communicate with
WSO2 ESB server 4.6.0.

Here is example. I would like to have `http://myesbserverinternaladdress:8280/services/MySomethingEndpoint` visible to internet with address `http://my.public.address/services/MySomethingEndpoint`

I have tried to configure apache mod_proxy and changed configuration in repository/conf/axis/axis.xml (there was some help in comments), but without luck so far.

Is there guides/howtos/references how I can achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to pass the messages through httpd, you can accomplish this by configuring httpd to act as a reverse proxy.

Following articles may help:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html
http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies

Comment: thank you. I would also have some information about WSO2 configuration. What is role of setting <parameter name="proxyPort">80</parameter> and what the value should be?